# LVDS connections for V29 LCD driver board

Tags: lvds

I am trying use LP154W02 B1K7 LCD (from Acer 5670 laptop) with V29 LCD driver board. As per datasheet, LP154W02 B1K7 LCD is 2 channel 6 bit, 3.3v, 1680x1050 resultion. Original LVDS connections from the laptop has 1-7 pins used  for power and next 8 pins are used as follows 
 9(Odd1_P),12(Odd2_p),15(Odd3_p),18(Odd_Clock_P),21(Even1_P),23(Even2_P),27(Even3_P),30(EvenC_P). Refer attached picture top one.[image]

Bottom LVDS cable (from the above picture) is actually used and surprisingly display worked but text is very grainy. I have used following driver bin file 
"MV29P_PNL_M201Z2_1680X1050_DO6L_12V_A_7KEY_NO_LOGO_IR_G32_FAC_LL25_NEC_LL131015_LAMV29"

So here are my questions.

1. When panel is rated 3.3V but above driver worked. Problem is Text is grainy/pixlated.
2. Original LVDS cable used only positive connections (9,12,etc) across odd and even pins. Should I use these connections?
3. If only positive connections (9,12,...) are used, should v29 driver able to drive it?
4. How come driver software 12V (observe 12V in bin file folder name) worked against 3.3v?
5. Can we get 3v driver software for v29 board? Is it ok to have 5v/12V, do they not burn the LCD??

Any suggestions are welcome and thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Where's the documentation for the board you're using? CAn you draw a connection diagram? Where does that driver come from? What do you mean with 'positive connections'? How do you know the 12V in the driver name has anything to do with the voltage?

Comment: LVDS connections support 6 or 8 connections Even and Odd. Each even and odd connection has 2 wires further positive and negative. Datasheets can be googled easily, but here is one https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf/722909/LG/LP154W02-B1K7/1  if you have used chinese LCD driver boards, one would realize driver bin files arranged in folders such a way folder names gives the configuration of LCD panel the driver supports.